# Specify a WorkManager when defining @Asynchronous method

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, asynchronous, ejb-3.1, weblogic12c

Is it possible to specify which **commonj.work.WorkManager** should be used for the processing of a method that is tagged @Asynchronous?

In the WebLogic 12.1.3 app I am enhancing, we were previously defining work managers and injecting them using:

```
@Resource(mappedName = "vm/myWorkManager")
private WorkManager myWorkManager;
```

... and scheduling asynchronous work like so:

```
rjscWorkManager.schedule(new DetailWork(businessId));
```

I would like to define @Asynchronous methods so that the asynchronous code can benefit from CDI injection, but I also want to have control over how many threads are allocated to the work.  Can this only be achieved by defining an application wide work manager?  I don't see anything in the EJB spec or the WebLogic documentation relating to @Asynchronous and work managers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can limit the number of threads assigned to @Asynchronous methods by assigning the EJB to a work manager in ***weblogic-ejb-jar.xml***:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<weblogic-ejb-jar
  xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-ejb-jar"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_0.xsd http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-ejb-jar http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-ejb-jar/1.2/weblogic-ejb-jar.xsd">

  <!-- Define which work manager the EJB(s) should use -->
  <weblogic-enterprise-bean>
    <ejb-name>MyService</ejb-name>
    <dispatch-policy>myWorkManager</dispatch-policy>
  </weblogic-enterprise-bean>

  <!-- Other EJBs could use the same work manager... -->

  <!-- Define the work manager -->
  <work-manager>
    <!-- Name -->
    <name>myWorkManager</name>
    <!-- Min Threads - Guarantees the minimum number of threads the server will allocate to requests -->
    <min-threads-constraint>
      <name>myWorkManager-MinThreads-Constraint</name>
      <count>5</count>
    </min-threads-constraint>
    <!-- Max Threads - Guarantees the maximum number of threads the server will allocate to requests -->
    <max-threads-constraint>
      <name>myWorkManager-MaxThreads-Constraint</name>
      <count>100</count>
    </max-threads-constraint>
    <!-- Capacity - Causes the server to reject requests only when it has reached its capacity -->
    <capacity>
      <name>myWorkManager-Capacity-Constraint</name>
      <count>-1</count>
    </capacity>
  </work-manager>
</weblogic-ejb-jar>
```

More details can be found here:

https://roundwheeltech.wordpress.com/2016/06/07/assigning-ejbs-to-work-managers/